# How to use Android emulator via VNC

Tags: android, android-emulator, vnc, qemu

I want to provide access to an Android emulator via VNC to let people test my App.

So far I could start the Android emulator with following command:

```
emulator -avd ice -verbose -qemu -vnc :2
```

I could also connect to it at port `5902` but I can't do any input, I don't know how to forward my mouse to the qemu.

Comment: Why not use one of the several VNC apps in the Play store? For the server being reachable from the outside world, you would have to setup the emulator network properly though (bridging or NAT, maybe in combination with a tunnel).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I *guess* the parameter "-qemu -vnc" will not work for android emulator's input. There are two hints: (1) the "-vnc" parameters are directed to qemu instead of android-emulator, and qemu-vnc may not support android's inputs (2)the VNC protocol does not define the "drag"/"move" which is a common operation for mobile.

However, there is a solution for your requirement:

1. Shut down the display of the emulator (optional) by using:

   emulator @avd -no-window
2. Install a vnc server. I recommend fastdroid-vnc, which is pretty good.
   (https://code.google.com/p/fastdroid-vnc/)

In this way, your emulator display is just like the effect of "-qemu -vnc :2" with inputs. BTW, the "drag" is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by starting a vnc server on your machine on display `:2`, informing android emulator to use this display and start the emulator:

```
vncserver :2 -geometry 1080x1920 -depth 24
export DISPLAY=2
emulator -avd avd_name -qemu
```

There are several vnc servers for Linux. I recommend tightvnc (package `tightvncserver` on Ubuntu).

`vncserver` will probably run your `xstartup` script located at folder `.vnc` on your home folder. If you don't want that, just comment all lines on this file (deleting the file won't help).

`geometry` should be screen dimensions of your avd. And it should have no skin.

Comment: shouldn't it be export `DISPLAY=2`?

Comment: Corrected it, @Leibovich. Thanks.